# Remove line break

Tags: vba, powerpoint, line-breaks

I want to remove the line break that I have in a certain text. I check in this forum how to do it and there were several answers but no one works for me at least in powerpoint.

I saw one example with left method:

```vb
    If Len(myString) <> 0 Then
        If Right$(myString, 2) = vbCrLf Or Right$(myString, 2) = vbNewLine Then 
            myString = Left$(myString, Len(myString) - 2)
        End If
    End If
```

`text = Left (text, number)` gives me Type mismatch error

`text = Left$ (text, number)` gives me `compile error: Type-declaration character does not match declared data type.`

I also try to replace the line break with "" but it just did nothing. It didn't gave me an error but the line break was still there.

The line break that I am using is `vbCrLf`

Comment: how did you declare `text`? Did you think of using the `Replace` function?

Comment: do you mean that you want to remove/replace last paragraph symbol at the end of your text or you want to remove all of line breaks within it? do you want to do it in any textbox, table cell or where?

Comment: maybe I didn't explain well myself... What I want is to copy each paragraph and add text to it. So I use ActivePresentation.Slides(sliNum).Shapes(shaNum).TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(i).text. The problem is that when I put it in a MsgBox the rest of the text that I add appears in another line and it is because I have a line break. I want to remove it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely that versions of PPT since 2007 don't use VBCrLf as a paragraph-ending character.  This explains which versions use what characters for line or paragraph ends:

Paragraph endings and line breaks
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00992_Paragraph_endings_and_line_breaks.htm

It's from the PPT FAQ site that I maintain.

Comment: Wow - that explains all kinds of things I had observed, and that had left me puzzled! Microsoft never cease to amaze me with their inconsistency...

Comment: My eyebrows alternate rapidly between "frown" and "startle" modes.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For the object in which you want to remove the `vbCrLf`, try using

```
myObj.TextFrame.TextRange.Replace vbCrLf, ""
```

If you want to do this to a string (not an object) you can try something like this:

```
Sub stripStrings()
Dim longString As String
Dim stringCopy As String

longString = "first paragraph" & vbCrLf & "second paragraph" & vbCrLf & "third paragraph" & vbCrLf
stringCopy = Replace(longString, vbCrLf, "")
MsgBox "longstring is now:" & vbCrLf & longString
MsgBox "stringcopy is:" & vbCrLf & stringCopy
End Sub
```

As you will see, this removes the line breaks. Adapt for your purpose...

**edit** As Steve Rindsberg pointed out, it may be that your version of Powerpoint is using something other than `vbCrLf` as the paragraph delimiting character.  Here is some code to help you figure this out - for each shape with text in it, it will extract the text, showing all "control characters" (ASCII value < 32) as `\xnn` where `nn` is the value of the control character (so that `vbCR` will display as `\x13` for example):

```
Sub displayControlCharacters()
Dim sh As Shape
Dim t As String

For Each sh In ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes
  If sh.TextFrame.HasText Then
    sh.Select
    t = sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text        
    MsgBox "The shape contains: " & vbCrLf & escapeString(t)
  End If
Next sh
End Sub

Function escapeString(t As String)
Dim ii As Integer
Dim r As String
For ii = 1 To Len(t)
  If Asc(Mid(t, ii, 1)) > 31 Then
    r = r + Mid(t, ii, 1)
  Else
    r = r + "\x" + Format(Asc(Mid(t, ii, 1)), "0")
  End If
Next
escapeString = r
End Function
```

A simple test showed that in PowerPoint 2010 you do have just `\x13` at the end of a paragraph...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using a String so I cannot use text.Replace vbCrLf, "". Actually I am using the each paragraph of a textBox But If I do what you write all the paragraph are removed and I want to mantain them so I have to copy the content of each paragraph in a string and after try to remove the line break to this string.

Comment: Updated answer - using the `Replace` function as it applies to strings rather than objects.

Comment: It is still giving me the same error. I am doing the following: text = sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(1).text and textS = Replace(text, vbCrLf, ""). Then when I try to show it with MsgBox textS & "more text" the second string appears in a different line.

Comment: Then following @SteveRindsberg's excellent suggestion, you might want to use `textS = Replace(text, vbCr, "")`.